# GNU Octave: How to change base from DEC to BIN?

Tags: gnu, octave

I need to do many binary calculations of the form:

```
10.1^(1/11) base 2
10.001^(1/11) base 2
10.0001^(1/11) base 2
10.00001^(1/11) base 2
10.000001^(1/11) base 2
...
```

where 1/11 base 2 = 1/3 base 10.

I don't want to use `bin2dec` and `dec2bin` for binary. I want to do calculations like in DEC, without worrying about the cumbersome functions. So how can I do the binary calculations in Octave?

Comment: You should label your radices: (10.1 base 2)^(1/3 base 10) (if that's correct) so your question is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long answer is, it's possible, but you'll have to a) program it yourself, or b) get someone to program it for you.  This method of writing fractional base-2 just isn't used in computing.

Programming a function to convert this representation of fractional binary numbers into standard IEEE754 double-precision floating point binary isn't impossible, so if it's an absolute must-have, it is doable.

Comment: Yes, but Masi's fundamental problem here is trying to get octave to interpret "10.1" as the binary 2 + a bit, as opposed to the decimal 10.1.  The 10.1 absolutely has to be encapsulated as a argument to some functiont, but that is exactly what masi is trying to avoid - those "cumbersome functions" - so now you're right back where you started, a function to convert the number from it's hybrid binary format to a format understandable by octave..

Comment: correct (see my comments under your answer).  this answer is clarifying exactly what he must do to accomplish what he wants to accomplish it -- despite being exactly the way he doesn't want to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't.  If I read your example right and 10.1 is supposed to be a binary floating point number?, then  bin2dec is not really appropriate unless your number are all strings.  I'm unaware of the concept of 'floating point binary' in octave.  I think you'll have to manage the mantissa & exponent manually yourself if you want to do that.

If you're set on all bit arithmetic, have you tried the [bit manipulation functions](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_42.html)? bitset, etc.?

Comment: now that sounds like a conversion problem: just need to find a way to auto-convert his string to some binary-float format that Octave will understand.

Comment: ~quack: everything is now in Binary, conversion is not my problem. I want to change base in the environment, not needing to worry about conversion all the time.

Comment: Masi, computers don't read floating point numbers in that kind of binary.  they use IEEE754 or other representations.

Comment: eg your "10.1 base 2" = 4.5 base 10 = 0x40900000 in IEEE754 single-precision floating point format.  (or does it?  did i get the conversion to base 10 right?)  see http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html

Comment: oik? regards. xxxxxxx

Comment: @Masi - 10.1 is NOT a binary representation of any kind in octave.  **It doesn't exist**.  In your first line you have 10.1 - take this number and subtract 1 from it.  What do you see?  Do you see 1.1? or 9.1?  You see 9.1.  Octave is always going to interpret this as decimal unless you do something to declare it as otherwise.

Comment: which is a shame; it doesn't seem like a generic fractional-number-in-base-n would be that difficult to program.  i remember working out binary numbers in exactly this format when learning basics for a compsci course.  of course, next thing we learned was how to take that and put it into IEEE754 for actual use.  but a generic base-n module would be handy, particularly for education.

Comment: Yes, but @Masi want's octave to just "know" that 10.1 is binary in this instance.  Think of all the possible ambiguities associated with an "arbitrary base" calculation system.  What becomes the result of 7 * 10? is 10 binary, octal or decimal? Given that, 14, 56 & 70 are all valid answers.  I would recommend something like eval_base(7 * 10, 8), so that eval_base has the information it needs to know what number base to use (i.e. 8)

Comment: Just to be clear `eval_base` is a function that doesn't exist. You'd have to write it ;-)

Comment: sure, lots of ambiguity.  but lots of potential solutions too.  if i call "set_base 8", then calculate "7*10", which have i asked for?  or maybe i need to call separate "set_input_base" and "set_output_base" functions.  math systems like this already make assumptions about the user's preferred base (eg, assume base-10 unless preceeded by 0x; output base-10 unless explicitly told otherwise).  an arbitrary-base system would still make assumptions, it just provides an easier way of overriding those assumptions.